# Convert Ajax jquery to Axios

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, axios

My page was using ajax requests but we are moving them to axios.
I have changed the code but the response data is coming empty.

This was my old code:

```
export function getMList(params, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    const url = `/admin/list`;
    const {
        name,
        type
    } = params;

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: $.param({name, type}),
        success: (response) => {
            onSuccess(response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
            onFailure(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Now after changing it to axios it is :

```
export function getMList(params) {
    const {
        name,
        type
    } = params;

    axios.get(`/admin/list`,params,{
        headers : {'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
        }
    }).then((res) => { return res; }, (err) => { return err; })
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Is it the data I am passing as params ?

The query is used here :

```
export function getMList(id, name, type) {
    const encodedName = encodeURI(name);

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestMList({ id }));
        admin.getMList({ name: encodedName, type },
            (response) => {
                dispatch(receivedMList({ id, name, type, response }));
            },
            (error) => {
                dispatch(failedMList(id));
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a then and catch as a normal Promise?

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios request methods such as `get` accepts two parameters, the request url and a [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) object. Inside the config object you will need the `data` key to set the request body (your `params`) and the `headers` key (your content-type).

```
export const getMList = (params) => {
  return axios.get('/admin/list', {
    data: params,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });
}
```

Since axios returns a Promise, and the above function returns the axios request,  you can then chain your "success" and "failure" logic using `.then` and `.catch` rather than passing them in as callbacks.

```
admin
  .getMList({ name: encodedName, type })
  .then((response) => dispatch(receivedMList({ id, name, type, response })))
  .catch((err) => dispatch(failedMList(id, err)));
```